# Aligning checkboxes with description text in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following layout tusing react JS. [image]

this the code I'm using to generate each one of these checkboxes

```
const CheckBoxItem = ({ Label, item, paramField, change }) => {
    return (
        <div className="Search-Input-CheckBox-Item"   >
            <input type="checkbox" checked={item} onChange={

                () => {

                    change()
                }} />

            <p className="Search-Input-Check-Label">{Label}</p>
        </div>
    )

}
```

the parent div of the items

```
 <div style={{ paddingLeft: '1%', paddingRight: '1%', borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.6' }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
```

I'm using justify-between to distribute the items horizontally, However I would each one of them to be vertically aligned. Can anyone give me some hint on how to do that?

Comment: proberly the easiest way would be CSS-Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use grid instead of flex, your second div could then look something like this

```
<div style={{ display: 'grid', gridAutoFlow: 'row', gridTemplateColums: "repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr))", gap: "1rem" }}>
```